# Difference between doAfterTerminate and doFinally

Tags: java, rx-java2

Does anybody knows what is the difference between operators "doAfterTerminate" and "doFinally" in RxJava 2 ?

Comment: Have you looked at their JavaDoc: [doAfterTerminat](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#doAfterTerminate-io.reactivex.functions.Action-) and [doFinally](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#doFinally-io.reactivex.functions.Action-)?

Comment: Thanks!
I've looked at [docs here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators), but not at your links

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The difference is that `doFinally` executes the provided `Action` if the downstream cancels/disposes the sequence in addition to the regular `onError` or `onComplete` termination paths. This allows cleaning up and releasing resources by all three means. The operator also guarantees that the action gets executed exactly once per subscription even in case if the `onError` or `onComplete` signals race with a cancellation.

In contrast, `doAfterTerminate` only covers `onError` and `onComplete`.

You can emulate `doFinally` with `doAfterTerminate` + `doOnCancel`, however, being split a operation, the action parameters may be both executed and cause problems with non-idempotent cleanup logic.

Comment: After some testing it seems that doFinally() runs on the downstream scheduler, is that true or I'm missing something?

Comment: It runs on the scheduler that triggered the termination, which could be an upstream or downstream scheduler. There is not much you can do but have an action that uses `Schedulers.xxx().scheduleDirect` to execute the real cleanup action.

Comment: Well, I cannot access directly to the scheduler for the cleanup so in my case I cannot use scheduleDirect(). But, I just found that the operator unsubscribeOn() affect the doFinally() which is much more suitable in my case. So I have a little question, is doFinally() guaranteed to run on the scheduler assigned on unsubscribeOn()?

Comment: If the sequence completes normally, it runs on that scheduler instead.

Comment: So I understand that when the sequence doesn't complete normally doFinally()  will not be called on the scheduler registered on unsubscibeOn(). can you explain what it means completing not normally or give me a reference to an explanation?

Comment: If the sequence terminates with onError or onCompleted, the upstream's thread is used to execute the action. If the sequence is disposed before that, the thread calling dispose will run the action.