# RXJava Single after unsubscribe(), doAfterTerminate() not called?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I have the following code:

```
Single<Item> update(...) {
...
return Single.create(subscriber -> aCall.execute(..) {
public void onResponse(..){
subscriber.onSuccess(..)
}
public void onError() {
  if(shouldReset) {
    subscriber.unsubscribe();
  } else {
    subscriber.onError();
  }
}
}));
    }
```

When calling the method:

```
update(..) 
.doOnSubscribe(counter++)
.doAfterTerminate(counter--)
.subscribe();
```

I've noticed that the counter is never decreased if  `subscriber.unsubscribe();` is called. Why is that?

If I change from `doAfterTerminate()` in `doOnUnsubscribe()`, the counter is decreased.

Answer (score 4):

`doAfterTerminate()` will work in the case of termination due to an `onError` or an `onComplete`, but not unsubscription.

You can either use `doFinally` or combine `doAfterTerminate()` with `doOnCancel` to get the call also when unsubscribed.

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47306699/difference-between-doafterterminate-and-dofinally) for an explanation of the difference.

Comment: and what if I m changing doAfterTerminate() into doOnUnsubscribe() ? Will doOnUnsubscribe() be called from onSuccess(), onError() and onUnsubsribe()?

Comment: Just a note that 1.x doesn't have `doFinally`.

Comment: I know that, that's my I m planning to change to doOnUnsubscribe(). Is doOnUnsubscribe() called after onError, onSuccess() and unsubscribe?

Comment: Yes, after a stream terminates (complete/error) an automatic unsubscription happens, it will also be called if you call unsubscribe yourself (programatically)